# MS Teams Bot sign-in not working, says "This action can't be performed since the app does not exist or has been uninstalled."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating a simple MS Teams messaging bot that requires auth/sign-in.

I am using [https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities](https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/%7BconversationId%7D/activities) to send a non-reply bot message to user that includes a hero card with a sign-in button.

The body looks somewhat like this:

```
{
"type": "message",
"from": {
    "id": "abc",
    "name": "messaging-bot"
},
"conversation": {
    "id": "789",
    "name": "test",
    "tenantId": "456",
    "role": "bot",
    "conversationType": "personal"
},
"recipient": {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "test"
},
"attachments": [
    {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
        "content": {
            "title": "title goes here",
            "subtitle": "subtitle goes here",
            "text": "descriptive text goes here",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "type": "signin",
                    "title": "Click me to sign in",
                    "value": "<my-signin-url>"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

When user receives hero card and clicks sign in button, user gets the following error:

```
This action can't be performed since the app does not exist or has been uninstalled.
```

I have added my sign-in domain to valid domains, and uploaded app package to MS Teams, so not sure why I am getting this error.

The app is created through Developer Portal in Ms Teams. For now, we are just creating a simple messaging app that relies on the bot messaging endpoint

May someone help with this?

Comment: If you are using Microsoft AD, could you please confirm if below are added in valid domain section of your app manifest:
token.botframework.com
login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: Thank you @Prasad-MSFT! The OAuth Identity provider is my own website but adding login.microsoftonline.com worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft AD, Please add below in valid domain section of your app manifest:

```
token.botframework.com
login.microsoftonline.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick update on answer. I found that installing/uninstalling app when sideloading app is a bit buggy. Things worked after I closed my MS Teams client and re-opened it